# Keep track of object ids properly after creating elements with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, event-handling

I have created a list of items with an object inside my controller

```
$scope.devices = [
    {"id": 0, "name": "sw", "class": 'sw' },
    {"id": 1, "name": "mlr", "class": 'mlr'},
    {"id": 2, "name": "lvm", "class": 'lvm'},
    {"id": 3, "name": "ltc", "class": 'ltc'},
    {"id": 4, "name": "fr", "class": 'fr'},
    {"id": 5, "name": "cap", "class": 'cap'}
];
```

and ng-repeat in my HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="device in devices" ng-click="selected(device.id)"></li>
```

I can keep track of an item that is clicked with `$scope.selected` bound to my `ng-click` that's basic.

However, what about later on, in a directive when an even fires? How can I collect information from the element? Specifically the original object id it came from?

```
// A device is grabbed
ums.directive('draggable', function (){

return function ($scope, element, attr){
    // restrict: "A",
    // link: function (){}

    var el = element[0];
    el.draggable = true;

    el.addEventListener(
        'dragstart',
        function(e) {
            e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
            e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);
            this.classList.add('drag');

            // when this event is fired I want the corresponding object id from $scope.devices
            console.log(el.$scope.device.id); // my first inclination

            return false;
        },
        false
    );

}

})
```

Comment: Are you able to create a JSFiddle that helps reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Ant let me know if this Plunkr works correctly (first time use) http://plnkr.co/Ji1xe4la0LzYkWbYsWoI

Answer (score 2):

The `ng-repeat` directive creates a scope for each line that it adds to the DOM. On each scope will be special properties set by `ng-repeat`.

From the Docs:

> The `ngRepeat` directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given loop variable is set to the current collection item, and `$index` is set to the item index or key.

The scope inherits from `$parent` scope. In your directive's linking function, you can use `scope.$parent.devices[scope.$index]` to access the original but it is also on the local scope as well.

For more information see the [AngularJS ngRepeat API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

### Update with example

This example shows the directive getting the $index and also emitting a custom event for the controller to use.

**The directive**

```
ums.directive('draggable', function (){
    function postLinkFn (scope, elem, attr){
        console.log("instantiating directive");

        elem.prop('draggable', true);

        elem.on ('dragstart',
            function(e) {
                elem.addClass('drag');
                console.log("dragstart index =", scope.$index);
                //emit event for controller
                scope.$emit("umsDragstart", e);
                return false;
            }
        );
    }
    return postLinkFn;
})
```

**In the controller**

```
    $scope.$on("umsDragstart", function ($event, rawEvent){ 
         console.log($event);
         console.log(rawEvent.x, rawEvent.y);
         console.log("umsDragstart id =", $event.targetScope.device.id);
    });
```

Notice that the example uses `jqLite` methods on the `elem` parameter of the `postLinkFn`. Those methods are documented in the [AngularJS angular.element API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

The `$on` and `$emit` methods are documented in the [AngularJS $rootScope.scope API Reference - $on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on) and [API Reference - $emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit).

Comment: Thanks for this. Could you show me with code (my plunkr) how it could be accessed in both the local scope and the parent scope as you've explained?

Comment: @BenRacicot I added an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the directive inside the controller in which `selected()` function is written the you can assign the id to some scope variable and access it in directive.
else if you are using the directive inside a `ng-repeat` then you can set custom scope variable for directive and pass the current id to it.
or else give away a code example