# Loop on directive scope array via ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

In my directive, when I declare

```
scope.type = 'A';
```

then in html I can access `A` via code

```
<p>{{type}}</p>
```

But when I declare

```
scope.types = ['A', 'B'];
```

then in html when I use the following ngRepeat, I cannot get `A` and `B` printed.

```
<div ng-repeat="type in types">
  <p>{{type}}</p>
  <input type="checkbox" id={{type}} ng-click="checkboxClick()" checked>
</div>
```

The point of this question is, I have tried it works for `scope.ty = 'A'`, but does not work for `scope.types = ['A', 'B']` using ngRepeat

Do not why, please advise! Thanks a lot.

------------updates--------------

Here is a relatively "full" version of directive

```
app.directive('chartDirective', function(socketio) {
  'use strict';

  return {
    restrict: 'E', //E = element
    templateUrl: '../../views/partials/chart.html',
    controller: DataController,
    controllerAs: 'dataCtrl',

    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {

      scope.Watch = scope.$watch(function() {

        return ctrl.data;

      }, function(newVal) {

        if (newVal) {
           //many irrelevant codes here

          // test codes
          scope.ty = 'A';
          scope.types = ['A', 'B'];

          //many irrelevant codes here
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Could you post some of your code? Did you try printing only {{type}} with <p>, without the <input> tag?

Comment: hmm..my source codes are too long, let me think how to simplify it for you.

Comment: Where is your directive and what type of scope does it declare? false, true, or isolate? It could be fighting with the `ng-repeat` instance scopes.

Comment: Your example works as written: https://jsfiddle.net/m21of8js/

Comment: pls see the updated question @Ulydev

Comment: I am using directive instead of controller, is that going raise the prolem?@ShaunScovil

Comment: In your example, you never initialize `scope.types`...you only change it when `ctrl.data` is updated. That could be causing your problem. Can you reproduce the problem by forking the JSFiddle that I created?

Comment: pls see the updated question @georgeawg

Comment: question is I did not initialize `scope.ty` either. But it works. It does not work when I use ngRepeat.@ShaunScovil

Comment: Not sure if that would change anything, but I just realised that replacing $scope with scope in @ShaunScovil 's fiddle made it crash. Would it be a good idea to replace your scope with $scope?

Comment: yeah, good point, but I tried and it did not work. @Ulydev

Comment: @LongshengZhou `isolate` scope is not the problem. But you are setting the data inside a `$watch` callback hooked to data in your controller. Is `ctrl.data` defined? Is it changing?

Comment: @Ulydev a directive's link function doesn't use injection. The first parameter of the link function is always scope. It doesn't matter if you call it  `$scope`, `scope`, or `someScope`. The directive's controller function uses injection and in that case the name of the parameters matters. But that isn't the problem because he is setting the list inside the link function.

Comment: @georgeawg yes, it is defined, and changing when webpage is reloaded. The point of this question is, it works for `scope.ty = 'A'`, but does not work for `scope.types = ['A', 'B'];` using ngRepeat, I am thinking it still related with ngRepeat stuff, maybe

Comment: @LongshengZhou please look at this answer [ng-repeat creates a scope](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34442885/5535245). That's why I think the scopes are fighting.

Comment: @LongshengZhou have you tried using the `track by` syntax? For example
`ng-repeat="type in types track by $index"`

Comment: @JulianSoro thanks for suggestion, but it does not work either.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle?